# count tcp states of netstat command

Tags: bash, awk

How does 
 `netstat -n | awk '/^tcp/ {++S[$NF]} END {for (a in S) print a, S[a]}'` work?

The above command outputs:

```
TIME_WAIT 57
FIN_WAIT2 2
ESTABLISHED 36
```

`awk '/^tcp/'`search lines starting with "tcp", but what does `{++S[$NF]} END {for (a in S) print a, S[a]}` mean?

Comment: It is always recommended to add samples of input and output too in CODE TAGS so that we could see if any other or better solution could be provided too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please go through following explanation and let me know if this helps you. Since you haven't shown samples so didn't test it.

```
awk '
  /^tcp/             ##Checking if a line starts from tcp string.
  {++S[$NF]}         ##Creating an array named S whose index is last column($NF) value and increasing its occurrence each time it has same index by 1.
  END{               ##Starting END block of this awk code here.
   for(a in S){      ##Starting a for loop which loop through S array.
    print a, S[a]}}  ##Printing a value and S[a] value here.
' Input_file         ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Its like `awk` works in style of `BEGIN`--> whose statements will be executed before reading Input_file. `MAIN section`--> where Input_file will get processed. `END section`--> once whole Input_file is read then whatever statements are given should be executed, I hope this helps you.

Comment: Does `END` block starts to execute just after the iteratition of every input line?

Comment: @Hel, its like `awk` works in style of `BEGIN`--> whose statements will be executed before reading Input_file. `MAIN section`--> where Input_file will get processed. `END section`--> once whole Input_file is read then whatever statements are given should be executed, I hope this helps you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I would think the index of array should be integer. But in `awk`, it can be string.

Comment: @Hel, yes it can be either int or string you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at `netstat -n` output:

```
Active Internet connections
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q  Local Address          Foreign Address         (state)    
tcp4  0      0       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ESTABLISHED
tcp4  0      0       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ESTABLISHED
tcp4  0      0       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ESTABLISHED
tcp4  0      0       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ESTABLISHED
tcp4  0      0       xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx    xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ESTABLISHED
```

Here the first two lines are header lines. Remember, the script's goal is to print the number of sockets per state.

`/^tcp/` matches lines that start with tcp, so it omits the two header lines. Before looking at its action, consider what `$NF` does:

`NF` is a variable of the number of fields in the current line while `$NF` actually gets that field's, the last field, value—the socket's state.

Now it should be easier to understand what `/^tcp/ {++S[$NF]}` does: it sets and or increments the socket state in associative array (hash table) `S`.

The `END` block just prints the key / values of `S`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Request you not to put IP addresses over posts, better place dummy addresses like `XX` etc etc.